# Adding return at the end of a prototype

Tags: javascript

Does adding a return at the end of a prototype make a difference, even if the prototype itself isn't actually returning anything, only manipulating the DOM?

```
MyObj.prototype.DoStuff = function () {
    // do stuff here... may or may not return a value
    return; <-- code in question
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You would want to return a value for methods if you wanted to chain them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All functions in JavaScript implicitly return `undefined` if you do not include a `return` statement. Since you're including a `return` statement with no value the function will still return `undefined` just as it would had you not used the `return` statement.

Details of this are given [in the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x12.9):

> **Syntax**
>
> *ReturnStatement* :
>       `return ;`
>       `return` [no *LineTerminator* here] *Expression* `;`
>
> **Semantics**
>
> ...
>   1. If the *Expression* is not present, return (return, undefined, empty).

Therefore you would usually omit the `return` statement in your case. It would only be necessary if the function actually returned a value.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a quick response! Does it ever have an impact on performance? Someone explained it to me as if an explicit return told the function that you're done, and thus would perform faster.

Comment: It *may* be very, very, very slightly faster. But it will make so little difference in the real world that it's really not worth worrying about. Leave it out - it's quicker to type :)